# Extract date of tweet using R

Tags: r, twitter

I want to know how to extract the specific date of a tweet using R. So far, I have only found how to extract tweets from a specific date range but the date tweet that was tweeted does not appear.

Comment: with `twitteR` you can also use the returned list of tweets like this:  `tweets[[1]]$created`.  If you type `tweets[[1]]$` you'll see a menu pop up in Rstudio that will give you the options/entries in the list element.

Answer (score 4):

We need more information on what packages you are using and what you have tried so far. Assuming that you are using the `twitteR` package:

```
tweets <- searchTwitteR("stack+overflow")
tweetsDF <- twListToDF(tweets)
```

Dates and times are in a column called **created**. Use `as.Date()` to get just the dates or use the `lubridate` package for whatever date manipulation you need.

Comment: Why the immediate downvote?

Comment: upvoted answer and OP since both seem like valid questions (albeit the question could be more clear regarding what has been tried / what is not working)